# Error during installation of MySQL on Debian 10/arm64

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, apt

I try to install mysql-server on my Debian 10. Actually i run Debian 10 on Mac Paralells (M1). So parallels doesn't support intel based operating systems. So debian run on arm64.

I downloaded **mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb** package and i install it with **sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb **. This step ok.

But when i update system with **sudo apt update**, i get this errors:

> N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-apt-config/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
>
> N: Skipping acquire of configured file
> 'mysql-8.0/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository
> 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease' doesn't support
> architecture 'arm64'
>
> N: Skipping acquire of configured file
> 'mysql-tools/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository
> 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease' doesn't support
> architecture 'arm64'

So i can't install mysql-server. My understanding is that mysql does not support arm64 because my processor is arm64. How can i fix it ?

Comment: More accurately, Parallels supports both ARM & Intel… but your M1 won't run any VM expecting to run on intel. Parallels does support installing Debian as a ready-made VM, right from the Installation Assistant. See https://kb.parallels.com/125375

Comment: my problem is not related to running intel or not. I'm just wondering how can I install mysql-server in a virtual machine installed on arm? @Tetsujin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message you're getting is because you're using an external repository and that repository doesn't ship arm64 packages.  As a result, you won't be able to use it unless the provider (in this case, I assume Oracle) chooses to ship arm64 packages.

However, Debian does ship packages of MariaDB, which is generally compatible with MySQL, and can be used in most cases where one would want to use MySQL.  The package to install, should you want to do that, is `default-mysql-server`.

You could, of course, also download the source packages from the third-party repository you're using (assuming they're provided) and build them yourself in your VM.  You'd have to rebuild each subsequent version, though, so this will make applying security updates difficult, and I'd recommend a different solution.